# How to declare variables and register their addresses to an array at link time

Tags: c, linker, iar

**THE GOAL:**
I want different .c files to be able to declare variables and register the address of said variables into an array located at the beginning of linker section `__my_registry_section__`.

**user1.c**:

```
#include "register.h"

REGISTER(struct thing, myThing1);
REGISTER(struct thing, myThing2);
```

**user2.c**:

```
#include "register.h"

REGISTER(struct thing, myThing3);
```

The idea is that after compilation the array located at the beginning of the block in `__my_registry_section__` will contain entries:

```
(order does not matter)
[0] &myThing3
[1] &myThing1
[2] &myThing2
```

**THE CURRENT METHOD**:
I have a macro that first *declares the variable* and next *adds the address of variable into the section* by declaring a void* with an unused name that is directed by a pragma to be located in the next available space in the registry section where the order does not matter.

**register.h**:

```
#define REGISTER(TYPE, NAME)     TYPE _##NAME;   /* allocate data */     \
                                _Pragma("location=\"__my_registry_section__\"") void* whatever##NAME = &_##NAME  /* place address of data into array */
```

**THE PROBLEM:**:
The method works, but only if you explicitly reference the `void* whatever##NAME` (e.g. `printf("%x", whatevermyThing1)`). However I don't want to have to reference these variables.

The variable `void* whatever##NAME` is never referenced (it's only there as an excuse to place the pointer into the section), so it never gets emitted into the object file. I tried using `__attribute__((used))` but it appears to not be available in IAR C. I also tried adding `_Pragma("required=whatever##NAME")` in order to force the symbol to be used but the `#` character is supposedly illegal inside the pragma. But even if I hard-code one of the variable names like so `_Pragma("required=whatevermyThing1")`, the compiler complains with

```
Warning[Pe609]: this kind of pragma may not be used here
```

Is there a way to force the compiler to emit the symbol without using this pragma? Is there another completely different approach?

Note, there is an existing question ([Declare a variable and add it to an array at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975254/declare-a-variable-and-add-it-to-an-array-at-compile-time)) that's pretty identical to mine, but the solution is actually just building the array at runtime, so not useful.

Comment: What is the motivation for this being a compile-time construct?

Comment: Have you considered a preprocessor solution involving [Array Initialization](https://tutorialink.com/c/array-initialization.c)?

Comment: I want people writing the .c files that register vars to be able to add to the registry in a single place. If this was done at runtime and they had to make changes to their variables, they would have to change both the header and the code that registers them.

Comment: Hi Robert, regarding array initialization, in the system I'm working with there will be many files that register variables, but only one globally-accessible registry array with their addresses. So whoever declares the array will not know how to initialize it, right?

Comment: Array Initialization is the only *compile-time* construct that I know of.  I'm happy to be proven wrong, however.

Comment: What about if you could just place the addresses into a memory block, instead of into an array that's explicitly declared. As long as the addresses are dumped into some consecutive memory I can go in later and perform the initialization I need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225432/discussion-between-carlos-vazquez-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: Variables don't even have an address at compile time.  This seems like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What is the ***problem*** that you've already decided trying to get the run-time address of a variable at compile time is supposed to solve?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I guess I meant link time, not compile time. I can make a global pointer type and assign it the value of the address of some global variable (not inside the { } of some running code) and the linker will assign the pointer type the correct address. The problem I'm trying to solve is to have a distributed variable registration (where order doesn't matter, I edited the question) such that when the program runs, it needs to do no initialization to perform the registration (all at compile time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution to you problem. There is an object attribute `__root` that indicates to the linker that this object should be included in the output even if it is not referenced anywhere. If you add this attribute to the declaration of `whatever##NAME` it will be included in the linked binary. This slots easily into your current solution, you only need to update `register.h` as shown below.

```
#define REGISTER(TYPE, NAME)   TYPE _##NAME;   /* allocate data */     \
     _Pragma("location=\"__my_registry_section__\"") __root void* whatever##NAME = &_##NAME  /* place address of data into array */
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about IAR, but I can help with:

> I also tried adding _Pragma("required=whatever##NAME") in order to force the symbol to be used but the # character is supposedly illegal inside the pragma

You can stringify after concatenation, [like so](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html):

```
#define DO_PRAGMA(a)  _Pragma(#a)
#define REGISTER(TYPE, NAME) \
   /* allocate data */ \
   TYPE _reg_##NAME; \
   _Pragma("location=\"__my_registry_section__\"") \
   DO_PRAGMA(required=whatever##NAME) \
   void *whatever##NAME = &_reg_##NAME

REGISTER(struct thing, myThing3);
```

I believe overall the simplest solution would be to preprocess the files to find all occurrences of some unique string and generate a source file with a proper C-ish array definition. Or just create such file manually.

Comment: This is a solution to the stringification problem but the rest does not work. `#pragma required` does not work this way.

Comment: KamilCuk, how do you use the preprocessor to create another source file? This would be useful

Comment: Normally. `cc afile > outputfile`. I meant "preprocess" in the [data processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessing) meaning. There is for example zephyr OS that has a python script that scans all source files for `IRQ_CONNECT` statements before compilation takes place to generate a source file with interrupts registered. The job here would be the same - scan all source file for `REGISTER` statements and generate a source file with the array.